# CodeIgniter URL rewrite with Nginx

Tags: codeigniter, nginx-location

I'm trying to migrate a site under CodeIgniter from Apache to Nginx. My first tests show very good performances, so it worst the try.

But I can't find the correct Nginx configuration to replace those RewriteRules :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I found this recipe on Nginx website https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/codeigniter/

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

It works in most cases, except when I have a trailing slash. Meaning 
 http://example.com/controller/param/

will call http://example.com/controller/function/index.php (and return a 404)

instead of http://example.com/index.php/controller/function/ ...as it usually do with Apache rewrite.

I tried to add a rewrite :

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
```

But it redirect POST to GET, so I loose all my post data...

Any clue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps. Replace both occurrences of `<source_directory>`; with your correct value:

```
    server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         <source_directory>;
    rewrite_log  on;
    index index.html index.php;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*))
    {
        set $host_without_www $1;
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ $scheme://$host_without_www/$1 permanent;
    }

    # canonicalize codeigniter url end points
    # if your default controller is something other than "welcome" you should change the following
    if ($request_uri ~* ^(/welcome(/index)?|/index(.php)?)/?$)
    {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ / permanent;
    }

    # removes trailing "index" from all controllers
    if ($request_uri ~* index/?$)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.*)/index/?$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    # removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
    if (!-d $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    # removes access to "system" folder, also allows a "System.php" controller
    if ($request_uri ~* ^/system)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
        break;
    }

    # unless the request is for a valid file (image, js, css, etc.), send to bootstrap
    if (!-e $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
        break;
    }

    # use fastcgi for all php files
    location ~ \.php$
    {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME <source_directory>$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to apache .htaccess files
    location ~ /\.htaccess
    {
        deny all;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /40x.html 
    {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html 
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what in your code will prevent the loss of POST data in case of rewrite ? I've already tested `rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;`and it transform POST's into GET's

Comment: Try using the reverse proxy support instead. An example location section would be: 
 `location / {
  proxy_pass      http://localhost:8080;
  proxy_redirect  http://localhost:8080/ /;
  proxy_read_timeout 60s;

  # May not need or want to set Host. Should default to the above hostname.
  proxy_set_header          Host            $host;
  proxy_set_header          X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}`

Comment: Should I replace localhost:8080 with my domain/port ?